# Garmin Forerunner 225 for High intensity workouts

Tags: hiit, tracking, heart-rate-monitor

I would like to know if the above mentionned watch is suitable for high intensity, specially with bodyweight workouts and shadow boxing.

Comment: Shouldn't your be posing this question to Garmin?

Comment: @rrirower  this is my community, hopefully 'Garmin' is somewhere here:)

Answer (score 1):

Its main feature is that it measures your heart rate and can use it to calculate calories burnt over any exercise.

It's not as good as using a heart rate monitor strap because it measures at the wrist.

Apart from that, it seems like a pretty good fitness watch.

Comment: I have the garmin FR 235 and I must say the HR-accuracy is far from bad. It stays within 1 to 3 bpm of the strap.

Comment: I was just going of collated reports from the main fitness tech reviewers. YMMV